# Send a cookie with cross domain request

Tags: http, cookies

I have two domains: `domain1` and `domain2`

Let's assume the customer's browser has a cookie for `domain2`.

The customer is surfing on `domain1` and is being redirected to `domain2` via the form(POST method). Is there any way to send a cookie from `domain2` with this redirection request?

Comment: You can read the cookie with javascript, attach it to the url you are redirecting to and read it via the URL parameter on the second domain.

Comment: @Evert , Thank you for the idea! But how can I read a cookie from another domain? Isn’t this prohibited due to security reasons?

Comment: You can't, only the domain that *has* the cookie can read it.